# ServiceStack templates do not appear in VS2022 after installing the extension

Tags: visual-studio, servicestack, visual-studio-2022

I’ve installed the VS2022 ServiceStack extension but no template is selectable when I want to create a new project. From the extensions list I can see the extension is installed.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older .NET Framework projects had to be removed in the latest SSVS version

All ServiceStack project templates can be created from the start page

### https://servicestack.net/start